# Add item to Dictionary

Tags: vb.net

How do you add values to the list of strings in a dictionary if the key is found. If the key is found then you cannot add to the dictionary

```
   Dim DataDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String)) = New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))

     DataDictionary.Add("1", SAM, BOB)
'if key is found add Joe
   If DataDictionary .ContainsKey("1")Then
    'Add Joe
```

Comment: *that* dictionary wont work because you do not have an instance of it: `Dim DataDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))` then it is just `DataDictionary.Add(key, value)`  you will likely need a `New` list of strings to add.  All is revealed in [Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

Comment: Or to add to a specific entry in the dictionary, `DataDictionary(key).Add("Some Value")`

Comment: I rephrased my question.

Comment: You're initialization is wrong - should be `DataDictionary.Add("1", New List(Of String) { "SAM", "BOB" })` (Syntax may be a bit off).

Comment: ...and added code which will not compile...as before, *you will likely need a `New` list of strings to add*.  You need to use `New` to create object instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim DataDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
' ...
' Initialize dictionary with a list
DataDictionary.Add("1", New List(Of String)(New String() { "SAM", "BOB" }))

' ...
' Check for key and add another value.
If DataDictionary.ContainsKey("1") Then
  'Add to the list of strings
  DataDictionary("1").Add("new item")
End If
```

Comment: "new item" is not a `List(of String)`

Comment: @Plutonix if you suppose (that's a big assumption) that before the if  there is a _DataDictionary.Add("1", New List(Of String))_ then the code is correct